# Обобщить результаты DataFrame: группировка по группе ряда чисел заканчивающейся нулем

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

Есть ряд данных. В конце каждого ряда нужно указать "первое значение ряда", "последнее значение" и "экстремум - максимум" или минимум из ряда (в данном примере максимум). Строки с 0 нужно сохранить. Записывается в конце ряда так:

```
0           
0           
24.61           
24.82           
24.85           
24.9            
24.98           
24.93           
24.9            
24.89   24.61   24.89   24.98
0           
0
```

Если сделать такой код, то почему то слетает `last` и индекс конечно не сохранится, все слетает:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Desktop\\111.csv', header=None, names=['COUNT'])

df['first'] = 0
df['last'] = 0
df['max'] = 0

df['temp'] = ((df['COUNT'] > 0) & (df['COUNT'].shift(1) == 0))
df['group'] = df['temp'].cumsum()

df1 = df.copy()
df1 = df.groupby('group').agg({"COUNT":['first', 'last', 'max']})
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(1)
df1.columns = ['first', 'last', 'max']
df1
```

Пример [файла данных](https://dropmefiles.com/8Jfc8) и [что хочу получить](https://dropmefiles.com/EkQVU).

Comment: для датафрейма есть метод ```describe()```, который дает информацию по данным (типо: минималный, максимальный, медиана и тп по столбцам)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from itertools import product

def first(s):
    return s.loc[(s!=0).idxmax()]

df = pd.read_excel(filename)       

col = '<COUNT>'

mask = (df[col].ne(0) & df[col].shift(-1).eq(0))    
tmp = df.groupby(mask.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())[col].agg([first, "last", "max"])

new_cols = ["<first>", "<last>", "<max>"]
df = df.assign(**dict(product(new_cols, [""])))

df.loc[mask, new_cols] = tmp.iloc[:mask.sum()].values

df.to_excel("/path/to/result.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

Результат:

```
In [124]: df
Out[124]:
    <COUNT> <first> <last>  <max>
0      0.00
1      0.00
2      0.00
3      0.00
4     24.61
5     24.67
6     24.80
7     24.84
8     24.79
9     24.82
10    24.79
11    24.82
12    24.85
13    24.90
14    24.98
15    24.93
16    24.90
17    24.89   24.61  24.89  24.98
18     0.00
19     0.00
20     0.00
21     0.00
22     0.00
23     0.00
24     0.00
25     0.00
26     0.00
27     0.00
28     0.00
29     0.00
30    24.94
31    24.94
32    24.89   24.94  24.89  24.94
33     0.00
34     0.00
35     0.00
36     0.00
37    24.93
38    24.93
39    24.95   24.93  24.95  24.95
40     0.00
41    24.94   24.94  24.94  24.94
42     0.00
43    24.94
44    24.95
45    24.98
46    24.97
47    24.98   24.94  24.98  24.98
48     0.00
49     0.00
50     0.00
51     0.00
52     0.00
53     0.00
54    25.07
55    25.04
56    25.07
57    25.07
58    25.03   25.07  25.03  25.07
59     0.00
60     0.00
61     0.00
62     0.00
63     0.00
64     0.00
65     0.00
66     0.00
67     0.00
68     0.00
```

Comment: @Максим, вы можете запустить мой код без изменений указав `filename="222.xlsx"` - правильно ли работает код в этом случае? PS похоже вы забыли выполнить `def first(s): ...`